# How to know which server storm/bolt is running

Tags: token, apache-storm, facebook-access-token

I have a question related to Apache Storm. Currently we use some servers to implement Storm, our application needs facebook/Twitter tokens.

So we want to design like this: each token belongs to a specific server, when a bolt received tuple, it'll request a token which is specifically for that bolt running instance, this is to prevent token blocking if different servers use same token in a short time.

Anyone knows how to achieve this way, is there any way to know which servers of a running instance of bolt? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one token per bolt instance then add an instance variable to your bolt class to hold that token and initialize/cleanup that token at the appropriate times in the bolt lifecycle.

If you want to have a token for each machine then you can create a Singleton bean to hold one token for the entire JVM.  Note that if you want to have more than one worker on a single machine then you need to be happy with multiple tokens for each machine (one per JVM on the machine), or build a stand-alone middleware server that owns the token and which handles requests from multiple JVM's on the machine.  Even if that is acceptable you'll still need to work out how to make all of the bolt instances in a single JVM/worker share the one token for that JVM.